# Unity Animator, how can I delete the default transmission?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

[image]

How can I delete the orange arrow? If I delete the orange block, the arrow comes to another block!

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the orange default-transition is not possible, BUT you can redirect it to another state:

Rightclick a state and choose "set as Layer default state":
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Why would you?
Animator needs a state to start with. Without a default transition it won't be able to begin.

Comment: Thank you, I put the other transitions so they start with the empty orange block.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Entry block and select "Set StateMachine Default State" to move the default line to a new node.

Comment: A objectively better answer already exist since Jun. What's additional value does this answer bring to the topic? It's not a state machine question btw.